# Jquery slider CSS issue

Tags: jquery, css

I had a trouble in using a jquery slider, can anyone help me in the following issue.

I was been trying to add a **"jquery slider"** to my html page.But I got some troubles in the page because the Jquery slider(css,js) files are affecting my original css styles in the page,which led to the change of font-style in the menu..

Slider

```
<---- My original css --->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css" type="text/css">

<---- My original css --->
```

<---- Jquery css --->

```
<link href="css/ninja-slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/thumbnail-slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/ninja-slider.js"></script>
```

```
<style>
    body {font: normal 0.9em Arial;color:#222;}
    header {display:block; font-size:1.2em;margin-bottom:100px;}
    header a, header span {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 4px 8px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        border: 2px solid #000;
        background: #DDD;
        color: #000;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: center;
        height: 20px;
    }
    header span {background:white;}
    a {color: #1155CC;}
</style>
```

<---- Jquery css --->

Comment: Place your Index.css after you place all your CSS files. the sequence of CSS files does matter in code ! This might be the issue. Check it once and then revert.

Answer (score 0):

Try ordering your code like this.

```html
<html>
  <head>
  
  <!---- My original css --->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css" type="text/css">
  <style>
    body {font: normal 0.9em Arial;color:#222;}
    header {display:block; font-size:1.2em;margin-bottom:100px;}
    header a, header span {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 4px 8px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        border: 2px solid #000;
        background: #DDD;
        color: #000;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: center;
        height: 20px;
    }
    header span {background:white;}
    a {color: #1155CC;}
  </style>

  
  <!---- Jquery css --->
  <link href="css/ninja-slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="css/thumbnail-slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="js/ninja-slider.js"></script>
  
  </head>
  
  <body>
    
  </body>
</html>
```